# How to access webpage text data dynamically to system process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, web

I have a webpage with some form that I can access through a URL http://server... I also have an application written in C++ that I want to get that form data.

- How can I access a webpage through a c++ code?
- How can I get that form data from webpage to c++ code?
- Next I need to dynamically get this value when I edit any
  data in webpage and press submit.

How can I execute this approach in C++?  Should I choose any thread mechanism inside C++ or any socket?

Comment: you could use Websockets and https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp

Answer (score 0):

> - How can i access a webpage through a c++ code ?

The scheme of the URL implies that you can access it using the Hypertext Transfer Protocol. The specification of HTTP tells you how to use the protocol and you can write a client based on that. You may get away with much less work by using an existing implementation of HTTP client that has a C++ (or C) API.

> - How can i get that form data from webpage to c++ code ?

As it is a webpage, presumably the form is described in HyperText Markup Language. Check the content to be sure. You can write a HTML parser based on the HTML standard specification. You may get away with much less work by using an existing implementation of HTML parser that has a C++ (or C) API.

> when i edit any data in webpage and press submit , i need to get this data to c++ code .

The form will need to send the submit to a webserver that executes your C++ program. This is usually achieved through Common Gateway Interface. You may get away with much less work by using an existing webserver that supports CGI, and an existing C++ (or C) CGI library. If you choose to write the webserver yourself, then you could write the submit response as part of the webserver program and you won't need CGI, but that would probably make your server poorly reusable.

> should i choose any thread mechanism

Webservers typically use multiple threads to handle requests, and if you write your own server, then I recommend also doing so. It's not absolutely necessary however.

Also, if your client program that reads the form has other things to do than wait for the server to respond, then an asynchronous request allows you to do those other things while waiting.

> or any socket

If you choose to implement the client and/or the server yourself, then yes, you'll probably need to use sockets to communicate over network.